# Inverse of destructuring assignment: restructuring assignment?

Tags: coffeescript, variable-assignment

In addition to it's handy syntax for [destructuring assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring), CoffeeScript supports a similar syntax for constructing object literals:

```
a = 1
b = 2
o = {a, b}

> {a: 1, b: 2}
```

I couldn't find mention of this syntax anywhere, so I took to calling it [restructuring assignment](http://bytes.goodeggs.com/post/41935904836/restructuring-assignment-in-coffeescript).  Is there a conventional name for this construct?  If not, what are others calling it?

#### Update

*structuring expressions* is my new name du jour.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't related to assignment; this is just an addition to JavaScript's object literal syntax.

It's interesting that you seem to perceive it as "derived from" destructuring assignment, because in fact the opposite is the case: destructuring assignment comes from object literal notation, and isn't limited to the keyless subset you're describing. For example, `{foo: asdf} = bar` does exactly what you'd expect:

```
asdf = bar.foo
```

So that `{a: b, b: a} = {a, b}` is a very confusing way to write `[a, b] = [b, a]`.

You can also write `{@foo}` to produce `{foo: @foo}`, which is another useful shorthand (and of course it works in destructuring assignment statements as well).

If you really need a name for it, "object literal key inference" might be more accurate.

Comment: How 'bout "restructuring expressions"?  I think it deserves a name 'cause it was surprising to me when I first saw it and frequently useful once I picked it up.  "Object literal key inference" is certainly more explicit, but I feel the verbosity makes it hard to grok.  "Restructuring" makes the syntactic connection to "restructuring".